# JavaScript: How to get the px value of a calc() css property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element with the `right` property set by css with a `calc()` function.

```
left:calc(100% + 40px);
```

How can I use jQuery (or just JavaScript) to get the calculated px value of the left property?  When I use `.style.left` I get an undefined property error. When I use `.css('left')` the value returned is `calc(100% + 40px)`.  What I need is the same px value that's used in the browser's inspector for the "computed" left property.

[image]

Comment: Check out `offset` and/or `position`: https://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/HXra8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has two similar functions, either of which might be what you want:

[.position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/) and [.offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: we ask code samples when people ask question, but not when people answer?

Comment: @Zafar The jQuery API pages that are linked include code samples.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("left");
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not support the calc() value. You should rather use `.position()` or `.offset()`.

**to set:**

```
.offset({left: 40});
```

**to get:**

```
.offset().left;
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXra8/2/)**